# How do I add a column to scraped data?

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I'm doing some data scraping by iterating over a list of internal IDs to open a url and scrape table data but I can't figure out how to add that internal ID as a column so each table row also contains the internal ID for that iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out a way to do it. Not the most elegant but, effectively, after extracting the data from the page to a variable, I then loop over that variable and create the string I'm looking for. Then output that string to a csv file.